# How to turn on wire logging in AWS SDK v3 for Node

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-js-v3

How can I log the full HTTP request and response when using the AWS SDK v3 for Node / javascript?

Comment: This seems to be lightweight in SDK v3, or not well-documented. Search for loggerMiddleware or read [Migrating to AWS SDK v3 for Javascript](https://serverless.pub/migrating-to-aws-sdk-v3/) where it passes a logger to client constructors.